# Why is ri on Windows returning nothing?

Tags: ruby, cmd, rdoc

When I type `ri` at the command prompt it returns nothing:

> Classes and Modules known to ri:

---

How do I set this up properly?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can type `gem rdoc --all --overwrite` to have gem recreate ri and rdocs for all gems.

You don't say what version of Ruby you have installed, but 1.8.7 seemed to have problems remembering whether it had docs for the core and standard libraries. There was a gem called something like core-data that helped. If I can remember the real name I'll update this.

1.9.2 is better about its docs but I've seen times where I have to force the rebuild using the command above. A gem can act up, causing RDoc to puke, which ends up keeping all the docs from being generated so watch its progress and compare it to what `gem list` outputs as a sanity check. If that happens I have a shell script I use to walk through all the gems and rebuild their docs one by one. It's an easy piece of code to write and steps around the problem of a single gem killing the processing of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the path to your ruby install folder in your PATH variable.
You have to do it to be allowed to launch ri in your command prompt.
Otherwise you can use the entire path : C:\Ruby\bin\ri.bat